# sql query, total number of people who have taken more than 1 variety in a season

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name farmer data and it has attributes like farmer name, father name, pesticides, variety of crop etc (these attributes would be required for query).

I have to write a query for:

> Total no of people who has taken more than 1 variety of crop in a Season.

How can i write this query? I have tried this query but its not giving me a single answer.

```
select Farmer Name, Count(variety Of Crop) 
from farmer data 
group by farmer Name 
having count(Variety Of Crop)>1
```

Comment: What column(s) do you use to determine the season? Or is the data in the table limited to a single season?

Comment: there isnt any column named season in the table, variety of crop has data like CIM 463, MNO 654 etc, i have to find those farmers who take more than this variety of crop, you can ignore the words "in a season"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
select count(*) 
from (select 1 as y 
     from farmer data 
     group by farmer Name 
     having count(distinct Variety Of Crop)>1) x
```

Comment: Maybe you have to add a table alias. I added an x to the end of the query.

Comment: No column was specified for column 1 of 'x'. now its giving this error

Comment: I added a column name alias y.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for records where Farmers has more the One type of crop. The way you are Counting rows will give you all the farmers who has more than one record regardless of type of Crop using distinct will return list of farmers who has more than one Distinct variety Of Crop.

```
select Farmer Name, Count(DISTINCT [variety Of Crop]) NumOfCrops
from farmer data 
group by farmer Name 
having Count(DISTINCT [variety Of Crop]) > 1
```

**Edit**
To get the total Number of Farmers with more then one variety Of Crop. Try this..

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
    select Farmer Name, Count(DISTINCT [variety Of Crop]) NumOfCrops
    from farmer data 
    group by farmer Name 
    having Count(DISTINCT [variety Of Crop]) > 1
) q
```

Comment: its displaying all the farmer names with a same ans in variety of crops column. i need a single answer since it says total no of farmer who have taken more than one variety in a season

Comment: ok its giving me distinct number of farmers only as a single answer, its not giving me the total number of farmers who has taken more than 1 variety in a Season

Comment: it works :). thank you. But can you tell me why you have written 'q' at end of query.

Comment: @user3001684 and if any of the above answers were helpful please accept the answer and be a bit more descriptive in your questions, It helps to get the right answer a bit quicker :) and if possible show some sample data in you questions. and a desired result set. A good quality Question is more likely to get a quick and right answer as compare to poorly presented question. just some tips :)

Comment: ok thank you... i have an other question.. i have to find Average no of farmers in each Town. i have to write a query for the same table. say the table name is farmer data and attributes are farmer name, pesticides, town etc. i have written this query, i am a beginner so i can't figure out why its not giving me the correct answer. the query i have written is
select Farmer Name, Count(distinct town) from farmer data group by town

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Farmer Name])
FROM [Farmer Data] AS f1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM [Farmer Data] AS f2
  WHERE f2.[Farmer Name] = f1.[Farmer Name]
    AND f2.[variety Of Crop] <> f1.[variety Of Crop]
);
```

Basically, the self-semi-join (implemented with the help of `EXISTS`) produces an intermediate row set where for every row in the table another row exists with the same `[Farmer Name]` and a different `[variety Of Crop]`, i.e. farmers with only one variety are filtered out at this point. The final result is just the count of distinct farmer names in the intermediate row set.